# How long should we test every option in an A/B test?

Tags: navigation, research, ab-testing

Currently we have an app with a number of features that fit well into a tab navigation bar below the action bar. Because of the vision of having more features in the future, business guys want to have just everything in a "Sliding Menu".

I'm quite aware of the problem of sliding menus and the low level of engagement of users for those "hidden features". I suggest keeping features into the tab navigation bar like now and in the feature probably have a sliding menu for the less frequently use features.

Finally, because they are still unsure about what's better, I suggested A/B testing. So, how long should we keep each navigation approach live to have a strong data to compare? The time for any A/B testing is the same of it changes depending of the nature of what we are testing?

Comment: Please provide visual content (screenshot) to support your question as it could be relevant to answering your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Smashing magazine published a nice article about AB testing best practices and a link to calculator of audience you need to ensure your results are statistically significant.

Check these links:

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/06/the-ultimate-guide-to-a-b-testing/

https://vwo.com/ab-split-test-significance-calculator/